# NodeJs API responding with incomplete object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, object

I am trying to implement API using NodeJs that reads data from database collection and again form that data reads respective data from another collection and updating same object with  new key value pairs.

The objects are updating successfully but the API response that I recieve on Frontend is not updated with second collection values.

```
router.get('/exam/:_id' , (req , res) => {
    ExamModel.find({
        userId: req.params._id
    })
        .then(doc => {
            let i=0;
            for(let data of doc){
                i=i+1;
                ResponseModel.find({examId: data._id}).countDocuments()
                   .then(count=>{
                        data.responseCount= count;
                        if(i===doc.length){
                           res.json(doc)
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        res.status(500).json(err)
                    })

            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).json(err)
        })
})
```

The object recieved from ExamModel is

```
[
    {
        _id: "012",
        responseCount: 0,
        data: [array]
    },
    {
        _id: "015",
        responseCount: 0,
        data: [array]
    }
]
```

after ResponseModel the object become

```
[
    {
        _id: "012",
        responseCount: 5,
        data: [array]
    },
    {
        _id: "015",
        responseCount: 2,
        data: [array]
    }
]
```

But as a response of api, I am getting the first object not second.

And also I am getting error

```
(node:15012) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
```

Comment: [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] this says that its trying to send response which is already sent.. you should be using res.json outside of your for loop. you could simply push data to an arr and then respond at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `doc` object returned by the query will be in an immutable state. In order to modify the object, you need to convert it to a plain javascript object first.

You can perform the below operation before the `for` loop.

```js
const result = doc.map(d => d.toObject());
```

Now you can use the `result` object in you for loop and make modification the result object.

Regarding the `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT` error. The `for` loop will complete the iteration long before the count query returns the promise. This will make the `if(i===doc.length)` condition true multiple times.

You can use async/await function as below in order to solve the issue

```js
router.get("/exam/:_id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const doc = await ExamModel.find({ userId: req.params._id });
    const result = doc.map((d) => d.toObject());
    for (let data of result) {
      const count = await ResponseModel.countDocuments({ examId: data._id });
      data.responseCount = count;
    }
    res.json(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Interval Server Err" });
  }
});
```

Comment: There's bigger problem than that. He is looping over multiple data in `doc` but sends only the first iteration (on the second iteration he should get an error about cannot send headers that is already sent)

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I didn't notice that first. Thanks for pointing out the mistake, I have added regarding that in the answer